# Point compass to a particular co ordinate

Tags: android, coordinates, digital-compass

I am creating an android compass application.
However, I want to add a functionality where the compass will point to some co ordinate that I have specified. 
How can I achieve this.

Thanks and Regards,
Rohit Savant

Comment: You want to add a functionallity, & we want to see some of your efforts, Share some code you have done yet.

Comment: of course you DID some research, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to achieve you will need 2 Locations, your own and that of the target. Then you can use the `bearingTo()` method to determine the angle from you to the target:

```
Location me = ...
Location target = ...

float angle = me.bearingTo(target);
```